# A symmetric random walk on a finite line from 0 to up to x

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

A symmetric random walk ( probability of moving left by 1 = probability of moving right by 1) on a subset of the integers from $0$ up to $x$. Take some $y$ s.t. $0 \leq y < x$ and let the random walk be considered a success if starting at some $y < x_0 \leq x$ we are in the '$0$ up to $y$ subset' after $n$ steps. What is the probability of success after $n$ steps starting at $x_0$?

edit : At the boundary the walker is guaranteed to move back inwards for its next step. It simply bounces back.

Comment: What happens if we hit one of the boundaries?

Comment: At the boundary, the next step is guaranteed to be the integer one away from it. So essentially the walker bounces away from the boundary once hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the walk is reflected at the boundaries, it’s equivalent to an unbounded random walk in which the target for success is $T=[-y,y]+2x\mathbb Z$. In this unbounded walk, the position after $n$ steps is binomially distributed, so the probability for success is

$$
2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\mathbb1_T(x_0+n-2k)\;.
$$

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for this, I am struggling to understand the intuition behind the $(x_0 + n - 2k)$ term in the series?

Comment: @AlexHill: Ah, perhaps I should have explained the notation. $\mathbb 1_T$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) on the target set $T$, and $x_0+n-2k$ is its argument. That's where you end up if you start at $x_0$ and take $k$ steps to the left and $n-k$ steps to the right. So only those binomial coefficients are being summed that correspond to ending up in the target.

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense now! so the indicator function gives one iff $(x_0 + n -2k) \in T$ and $0$ otherwise? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @AlexHill: Yes, that's right. While I'm defining notation, I might also add that $[-y,y]+2x\mathbb Z$ is the set of all numbers $a+b$ with $a\in[-y,y]$ and $b\in2x\mathbb Z$, and $2x\mathbb Z$ is the set of all numbers of the form $2kx$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: perfect!! Thankyou!