# Hitting time of a random walk on a finite grid

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Imagine a symmetric random walk on a finite 2D grid $(m \times n)$ starting at $(x_0,y_0)$ taking steps either up, down, left, or right with equal chance. If there is a reflection on the boundary then what is the expected hitting time for a rectangular subset $(n-a) \times (m-b)$ in the 'corner' of the grid.

Edit: and what is the probability of hitting this subset in number of steps t?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this question is much much harder than your 1D version of the same (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639922/a-symmetric-random-walk-on-a-finite-line-from-0-to-up-to-x). I could be wrong, of course. What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: In particular, I think the request for a probability of being in the subset as a function of $t$ will be the challenge. The expected hitting time might be more tractable (emphasis on might).

Comment: @AaronMontgomery My initial thoughts were to find the probability in 1D and then model the 2D case as 2 separate 1D random walks where you flip a coin to see which of the two random walks moves next. And then the probability of being in the subset mentioned above would be the multiplication of the probabilities of these two independent random walks being in their 'success' regions at the same time. I do have concerns with this method though, thank you for responding!